# Problem when logging into the website using post in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I encountered a problem when logging into the website using `package: http`.
When I use

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var client = Client();
  var url = 'https://shop.ezskin.com.tw/account/login';
  var payload = {
    'customer[email]': 'test123',
    'customer[password]': 'test1234',
  };
  var response = await client.post(url, body: payload);

  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
}
```

`response.statusCode` shows 302, which means redirect, but `response.body` shows

```xml
<html>
  <body>You are being <a href="https://shop.ezskin.com.tw/account/index">redirected</a>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Results don't go to account details page as expected. After that I use `client.get`

```dart
var nextPage = await client.get('https://shop.ezskin.com.tw/account/index');

print(nextPage.body);
```

It goes back to the account login page.

1. So how can I correctly redirect to the account details page after login?
2. I thought that after using `Client()`, once I logged in correctly, before using `Client.close()`, making multiple requests to the same server is feasible, but the result does not seem to be the case. Is it something I did wrong?
3. In addition, should I encrypt the email and password before putting them in the parameter list?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Request/followRedirects.html

Comment: But it's default value is true, which I didn't chage it. Should I change it to false?

Comment: ooops, `Defaults to true` indeed strange - maybe `post` method changes that to `false`?

Comment: presumably you need to preserve the session cookie and send it with the second request

Comment: I added the cookie to `get` and it can be redirected correctly. I tried it. It seems that cookie must be added to each request to be in the same session. Is this normal?